# Import file from other folder in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to import **ContactUs.js** into **Footer.js** but cannot get it to work:

Here is my project structure:

[image: 1]

Here is how I've tried to import it:

```
import ContactUs from '../Pages/Contact Us/ContactUs.js'
import ContactUs from '../..Pages/Contact Us/ContactUs.js'
import ContactUs from './../Pages/Contact Us/ContactUs.js'
```

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: Can you create a code [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io)? We can help you to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It is good practice to either use `camelCase` or `snake_case` names for folders and files so rename folder name from `Contact Us` to `ContactUs`

```
import ContactUs from '../ContactUs/ContactUs.js'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import ContactUs from '../../Pages/ContactUs';
```

Normally you wouldn't include a page from inside a component so something might be a bit off with your structure.

Comment: I have a link in my footer that is redirecting to a new page. How should I have it instead?

Comment: Handle it via routing in your app. Don't load the page from your footer.

Comment: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web try this tutorial.